# Запятая перед "как мантру"

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, как

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая (и почему?) перед выражением "как мантру повторял"? Например в предложении: **"Он как мантру повторял фразу..."**

Answer (score 1):

**Он как мантру повторял фрАзу...**

Оборот в роли обстоятельства входит в основное сообщение и не обособляется. Но при распространении предложения обособление возможно: **Он, как мАнтру, повторял одну и ту же фрАзу...**

Повторять как мантру – это монотонно повторять много раз одно и то же.

Обособление устойчивого оборота зависит от его позиции и структуры предложения.

Оборот **не обособляется**, если он вписывается в структуру предложения с учетом расстановки логических ударений (это позиция наречия в роли необособленного обстоятельства).

Оборот **обособляется** со значением сравнения, а также если является уточнением по отношению к другому обстоятельству.

**Примеры:**

Все **как мантру** повторяют средний возраст… средний возраст.. а что в нем?
Обстоятельство.

Напоминаю-напоминаю,  вот только повторять одно и тоже каждый день **как мантру** откровенно надоедает. Обстоятельство.

Без устали, **как мантру**, он повторял: «Хочу быть учеником своих идей». Уточнение.

Ничего, ничего… … все пройдет… Мама шептАла это, **как мАнтру**. Сравнительный оборот.

**Примечание**

МАНТРА, -ы; ж. [санскр. mantrah от man - думать, мыслить] В индуизме: священное заклинание, которому приписывается волшебная, сверхъестественная и исцеляющая сила.

Правильно читать магические слова 3, 9, 18 или 27 раз, наиболее оптимальным числом считается 108. Самое важное – это соблюдение точности и ритма произношения. Только ритм и точно воспроизведенные звуки создают положительные энергетические вибрации.

Answer (score 0):

*Jasmin*, спасибо Вам за информативный ответ. 
К сожалению, изначально я несколько упростил интересовавшее меня предложение, и в своем вопросе в качестве примера привел только ключевую фразу из него. Из Вашего ответа я понял, что ключевой фразы может быть мало, а необходимость расстановки запятых может зависеть именно от нюансов целого предложения. С учетом Ваших объяснений я пришел к тому, что **не нужно** обособлять запятыми выражение «как мантру» в таком предложении: **«…  Тем не менее, с маниакальной настойчивостью продолжает как мантру повторять те же самые обвинения.»** (на выражении «как мантру» акцент не делается).
Если Вас не затруднит, подтвердите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я Вас понял и расставил запятые именно в таком предложении?